# Covariant of Inherit generic classes with type parameter is subclass

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

Covariant of Inherit generic classes with type parameter is subclass

I want to build a MVVM project. and I need to build a collection to contain some ViewModels.

these ViewModels are generic class. and some Models are similar. such as shape for triangle and rectangle...

I want to collect them to ONE colletion. so the collection use the base class type.

the problem is these Inherit ViewModels will not be recoganized as Subclasse's.

here is a Scenario ：

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public interface I { }   //interface

    public class M : I { }   //Model base
    public class MA : M { }  //Modle A
    public class MB : M { }  //Modle B

    public class VM<T> where T : class, I { }         //ViewModel Base
    public class VMS<T> : VM<T> where T : class, I { }//ViewModel Base

    public class VMA : VMS<MA> { }   //ViewModel A
    public class VMB : VMS<MB> { }   //ViewModel B


    public class Problem
    {
        List<VMS<I>> VMList = new List<VMS<I>>(); //


        public void StupidThing()   //   F: fail   O: Ok
        {
            VMList.Add(new VMB());  //   F why?

            VMS<I>  a = new VMB();  //1  F why?
            VMS<M>  b = new VMB();  //2  F why?   
            VMS<MA> c = new VMB();  //3  F
            VMS<MB> d = new VMB();  //4  O
            VMA     e = new VMB();  //5  F
            VMB     f = new VMB();  //6  O
        }
    }
}
```

In the function of **StupidThing** I know the line 3 and line 5 are wrong and line 4 and line 6 are ok. but why line 1,2  are wrong.

Comment: Just because two types happen to have a particular inheritance relationship between them, that does not mean that a single generic type *parameterised* by those types has the *same* inheritance relationship. A `List<string>` is *not* also a `List<object>` because if you were able to make that cast, you could store *anything* into that list.

Comment: "I want to build a MVVM project. and I need to build a collection to contain some ViewModels." Maybe look at how [MVVM light](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx) is doing just that and get inspired ...

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: **Thank you very much Both of you **
this problem have confused me for several weeks.
With you explain I realised that a List<cat> is not a List<animal>
A List<animal> variant could not accept a List<cat> instance.
because the variant accept a Dog  the instance NOT
thank you clarify me!!! you are awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMB implements VM<MB>, it means VMB may contains methods like (it's only example, it depends on VM<T> definition): MB GetModel() or void SetModel(MB m).

VMS<I> implements VM<I>, it means VMS<I> should contains I GetModel() or void SetModel(I m) with the same VM<T> definition.

There are two different signatures for GetModel/SetModel methods and some compliation problems. So, you can't simply cast VMB to VM<I> and use it in your collection VMList.